# Is it possible to access request.body multiple times in jooby/java

Tags: java, jooby

```
Mutant first = request.body();
Mutant second = request.body();

log.info("First: {}, Second: {}", first, 
    Strings.isNullOrEmpty(second.value()) ? "None": second.value()
);
```

yelds

First: {..my content..}, Second: None

Updated: 
Jooby library, just for FYI
https://jooby.org

Reqeust object used: 
https://jooby.org/apidocs/org/jooby/request

I looked the de-compiled code and it looks like they do not cache the body property, so if you need to access request.body() from multiple routes, well...

Comment: I would imagine not, given that those are usually streams and streams can only be played once.  What library are you using to send your requests in the first place?

Comment: Makoto, I do not see how " library are you using to send your requests" is relevant. In my case  jooby used for http, so a client could be anything from Chrome & IE to postman and curl

Comment: Vera: The code you've posted doesn't tell us what the type of `request` is, for instance. So we don't know what behavior you'd be right to expect. It would be easy to guess if you were using, e.g., `HttpServletRequest`s, but that class doesn't have the `body()` method. So @Makoto's question is relevant.

Comment: Oh it is jooby library, https://jooby.org/, this one: https://jooby.org/apidocs/org/jooby/request
I will update the original post, if I can

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible, but requires a work-around.

You can add this `use` block as the first line in your application. This allows you to access the body multiple times through `request.body()`. Internally the body will be streamed into memory and offloaded to disk if its too large in all cases, this work-around just makes sure you get the same reference every time.

```
// Cache body in request scope
use("*", "*", (req, res, chain) -> {
  final Mutant body = req.method().equalsIgnoreCase("post") ? req.body() : null;
  Request.Forwarding wrappedReq = new Request.Forwarding(req) {

    @Override
    public Mutant body() throws Exception {
      if(body != null) {
        return body;
      }
      return super.body();
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T body(Class<T> type) throws Exception {
      return body().to(type);
    }

  };
  chain.next(wrappedReq, res);
});
```

Any filter or route defined after this block will be able to obtain the request body multiple times. If the body was requested already before this `use` block, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like it.

Jooby implements [the `in` parameter (which is what `request.body` would eventually resolve to)](https://static.javadoc.io/org.jooby/jooby/1.3.0/org/jooby/spi/NativeRequest.html#in--) as a `InputStream`.  An `InputStream` cannot be rewound, and it would not have any context or ability to do so.  Therefore, multiple invocations of `request.body()` would get you the body of your request *exactly **once***.

Comment: thanks! I was hoping there is a magic flag or configuration setting that I'm missing...